# Using Mongo to continuously rollup data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I've been experimenting with the Mongo Aggregation Framework and, with help from folks on here, am able to generate the right set of output docs for a given input.  I have a couple of conceptual issues though that I'm hoping folks can help me design around.

The application I have is a runtime system that collects data for all the transactions it processes.  All this data is written to a distributed, sharded collection in Mongo.  What I need to do is periodically (every 5 seconds at this point) run a job that traverses this data, rolling it up by carious categories and appending the rolled up documents to a set of existing collections (or one existing collection).

I have a couple of challenges with the way Mongo Aggregration works:

1 - the $out pipeline stage doesn’t append to the target collection, it overwrites it - I need to append to a constantly growing collection.  It also can't write to a sharded collection, but I don't think this is that big an issue.

2 - I don't know how I can configure it to essentially "tail" the input collection.  Right now I would need to run it from a server and would have to mark the set of documents it's going to process with a query before running the aggregate() command and then have another job that periodically goes back through the source collection deleting documents that have been marked for processing (this assumes the aggregate worked and rolled them up properly - there is no transactionality).

Anyone have any suggestions for a better way to do this?

Thanks,

Ian

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at version 3.6 (released last Nov) and the feature known as change streams.  Change streams is effectively the "tail" you seek.   A compact program in pseudo-code would look like this.  Note also how we iterate over the agg on `inputCollection` and write doc by doc to the `outputCollection`.

```
tailableCursor = db.inputCollection.watch()
while(true) {
    // Block until something comes in;
    document = next(tailableCursor); 

    // Examine document to ensure it is of interest
    if(of interest) {
       cur2 = db.inputCollection.aggregate([pipeline]);
       while(cur.hasNext()) {
          db.outputCollection.insert(cur.next());
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks interesting, basically it looks like the if(or interest) would be replacing the match in an agg pipeline.  I'm curious aboiut the aggregate step here, will this essentially keep feeding documents "of interest" to the agg pipeline to be rolled up?

Comment: Not quite.   The docs are not fed to the pipeline; they're already there.  They were inserted into inputCollection and the watch() function woke up.  "of interest" is there just in case the wake up event is NOT something you care about, like maybe an update of an old record.  The agg() runs "fresh" each time, but each time the input set gets bigger.

Comment: I don't think that will work then.  The input set is already a couple of TB and growing all the time.  I need to rollup only the new records.  It seems like this kind of continual storage and rollup of time-series data must be a fairly common requirement.

Comment: Ah.  That's stream processing not a database.   In MongoDB you apply a variety of queries to (a large amount of) data, query->data.   In stream processing, you establish one query (or an agg) and flow small increments of data across it -- but at high volume and typically for a long time (minutes, days, etc.),  data->query